InvalidFEOpcode when running Hello ZoKrates
I'm trying to verify a proof by calling verifyTx() on the smart contract output given after running zokrates export-verifier, but it's reverting with the error InvalidFEOpcode on the code block:
assembly {
   success := staticcall(sub(gas(), 2000), 8, add(input, 0x20), mul(inputSize, 0x20), out, 0x20)
   switch success case 0 { invalid() }
}

...from the pairing() internal call of the verifier. I'm following the Hello Zokrates! example without changing anything.

Solc 0.8.25
ZoKrates 0.8.8

As a note, when running it against an anvil node, it throws this warning before reverting:
EIP-3855 is not supported in one or more of the RPCs used.
Unsupported Chain IDs: 31337.
Contracts deployed with a Solidity version equal or higher than 0.8.20 might not work properly.
For more information, please see https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3855

But when I run it against a mainnet fork the same error gets thrown, just that without the warning (tried with 0.8.18 and same issue).
If you need to see the full verifier, let me know and I'll add it as an edit. Thanks!

Good you also posted on Github. Hope you get an answer (and can self-answer here). Only other idea for now is to also try on Eth R&D Discord https://discord.com/invite/qGpsxSA maybe a channel like #cryptography.

Done with the approach @eth
